# Image Magick issues getting colorprofile

Tags: php, imagemagick

Im trying to get the colorprofile of any image and i cant seem to do it with imageMagick.  I can get the profile from some images with `exif_read_data`  but I need the profile from all images.  i found the function  `getImageProfile()`  but it does not seem to do anything.  When i use image magick i always run commands with `exec()`   do I have to install something else to run normal functions like the following?

here is my code that does work:

```
$newfile="tmp_image/someimage.jpg";
$comment=GetImageProfile($newfile,"comment");
print "-".$comment."-";
```

When i run that code, i dont even see the dashes, so the function is crashing php

Answer (score 0):

Are you using linux? I did this for centos..

```
yum install php-devel
pecl install imagick
service httpd restart
```

Also try ..

1) Turning on error reporting in the file

```
ini_set(‘display_errors’,1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

2) Try using another ImageMagick function to see if it is an
extension issue or if it's something else.

Comment: got stuck at `pecl install imagick`    is imagick not installed with image magick command line tools? i guess im confused on the difference between the two

Comment: I believe you need to install the extension to use the PHP function. What OS are you using? It seems like the issue is installing this extension and then you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i am running CentOS Linux 5.6